# polymer component that displays errors on the page

Tags: polymer

I am trying to figure out how to implement a Polymer component that will centrally handle errors that other components on the page might encounter. The idea is to have a single point of error handling on the page and have all components send errors to this error handler component.

The problem is I am not sure about the architecture of all this. I see two ways to do it:

1. let all the components be aware of the error handler component and when they see an error, let them look up the error handler component by ID and call a known method on it.
2. let all the components fire `error` events and have the error handler component listen to these events. The problem is how to find all components on the page to attach event listeners to. Also, what to do with components that are created on the page dynamically? Listen to DOM changes?

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy method is to have your handler component listen for error events on `document` or `window`, and then have your reporters fire the error events directly on that object (or let them bubble up).

Comment: thanks. is there anything special that I need to do when I call `this.fire('error', e)` in my component to report an error? where can I read about bubbling etc?